# How to use a wordpress container with a wp-cli container when /var/www/html is already mounted in the host?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-network, wp-cli

I tried using networks, but the network with the folder's name concatenated with "_default" is not found.

If I specify the network like this:

```
  wpcli:
    container_name: ...
    image: wordpress:cli
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wordpress
    networks:
      - A_default
```

I get:

> **ERROR**: Service "wpcli" uses an undefined network "A_default"

although `A_default` exists in the output of `docker network ls`.

If I remove the part:

```
    networks:
      - A_default
```

I get this error:

> **wpcli_1**       | Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
>
> **wpcli_1**       | Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.
>
> **A_wpcli_1** exited with code 1

and only this error in the `docker-compose up` output.

If I use

```
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html
```

inside the `wpcli` section of my `docker-compose.yml` I get the same error.

## `docker-compose.yml`

Below is my `docker-compose.yml` with sensible information replaced with `...`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: A_db_1
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '...'
      MYSQL_USER: '...'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '...'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ...

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: A_phpmyadmin_1
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db:3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_PASSWORD: ...

  wordpress:
    container_name: A_wordpress_1
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./html
        target: /var/www/html
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: '...'
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: '...'
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '...'
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: 'wp_'
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: '...'
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY: '...'
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: '...'
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: '...'
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT: '...'
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: '...'
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: '...'
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: '...'

  wpcli:
    container_name: A_wpcli_1
    image: wordpress:cli
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wordpress
    networks:
      - A_default

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Thank you.

## Update 1

I have seen [this file](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/c63f536e5d24b474c93e6c4b8deeacf95a89eb64/php7.2/cli/Dockerfile) but I do not find it helpful in my situation.

## Update 2

I wish to use a separate container just for WP-CLI because the command

```sh
docker run -it --rm \
    --volumes-from A_wordpress_1 \
    --network A_default wordpress:cli \
    $*
```

does not remove the container after it has done its job, and removing `--rm` makes me unable to work with the files it has created because I cannot access the volumes of `A_wordpress_1` because the temporary WP-CLI container has a different working directory.

Comment: An extra container for just WP-CLI?

Comment: @leymannx I have added the section `Update 2` to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your docker-compose file:

1. (removed) `networks` section was malformed
2. `./html` not mounted in `wpcli` service

I would try the following:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    ...
  phpmyadmin:
    ...
  wordpress:
    ...
  wpcli:
    ...
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./html
        target: /var/www/html
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    ...
volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  A_default:
```